# Tkinter Toplevel type error

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4, typeerror, toplevel

I'm stumped (once again) and hoping i can find help here.
im working on a tkinter application and ran into an a type error that i cant seem to figure out.

This is a condensed version of the original code that i used as a test

class App():

```
def __init__(self,master):

    master.configure(background = '#002e3d')
    master.title = master.title('Wiki Me!')
    master.geometry = master.geometry('660x550+200+200')
    master.resizable(width = False,height = False)
    master.focus_set()

    self.button1 = tk.Button(master,text= 'test', bg= 'grey', command= self.search)
    self.button1.pack()   

def search(self):
    new_window = new()
```

class new():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.window = tk.Toplevel()
    self.window.title('find')
```

def main():

```
root = tk.Tk()
window = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So running this causes a type error 
'Str object is not callable'

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
if it matters im on linux and running python 3.4 with idle.

Comment: What have you done to try to resolve this? Do you understand the error message? Have you examined the variable causing the error to see if it contains what you think it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is due to something like this happening.

```
my_string = "Hello World!"
my_string() # <-- Causes error
```

When you change the title of the window using `master.title(str)` it returns an empty string `''`. With this line, the title of the master window is changed to `'Wiki Me!'`

```
master.title = master.title('Wiki Me!')
```

But the value for `master.title` is now an empty string instead of something like the following

```
<bound method Tk.wm_title of <tkinter.Tk object at 0x0000000003077320>>
```

Now when you create a new Toplevel window it uses the title of the `Tk` instance which in this case is `master` as a default. Because the title is now a string instead of the natural bound method this causes issues when creating the Toplevel instance. All you need is

```
master.title('Wiki Me!')
```

Comment: That totally fixed it! Thank you so much. Very very helpful